# ConfusionMatrix on Logistic Regression model in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to calculate confusion matrix on my logistic regression model but getting an error

> Error: data and reference should be factors with the same levels.
> In addition: Warning message: In is.factor(reference) : NAs introduced
> by coercion

Code:

```
usage_model_rl <- glm(data = train_usage_rl, formula = Subscription ~., family = binomial(link = "logit"))
usage_predictions <- predict(usage_model_rl, test_usage_rl, type = "response") %>%
  bind_cols(test_usage_rl %>% dplyr::select(Subscription), preds = .)


cut04 <- usage_predictions %>%mutate(predicted = ifelse(preds >= 0.4, 1, 0)) %>% dplyr::select(-preds) %>% dplyr::select(predicted, Subscription) %>%mutate_all(list(~ factor(., levels = c(1, 0)))) %>%table()

confusionMatrix(usage_predictions,as.numeric(test_usage$Subscription),positive==1)
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
confusionMatrix(usage_predictions,test_usage$Subscription,positive="1", dnn=c("Prediction", "Reference"))
```

Make sure they're all factors.